# Getting started with MySQL collation order

Tags: mysql, collation

It seems to be unreasonably difficult to get off the ground with MySQL with respect to collation order. I have been reading StackOverflow Q&A on this subject all day and have learned a lot, but still cannot get a very simple example to work.

What I want to do is:

1. Create a database that supports Unicode characters (for example `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`).
2. Add a table with a `VARCHAR` column in it.
3. Write a stored procedure that takes a `VARCHAR` parameter and returns matching rows from the table.
4. Call this stored procedure from (in my case) HeidiSQL without returning `SQL Error (1267): Illegal mix of collations`

This is the kind of thing that I think ought to be extremely simple, and is extremely simple in SQL Server, but is actually extremely difficult in MySQL.

If someone who understands this stuff could write some simple getting started steps this would be very helpful.

Comment: You just have to make sure that you either use the same collation consistently for your field / creation of the stored procedure / connecting to the database when you execute the stored proc, or you need to have explicit coertion of text to a common collation. Pls first do some debugging to determine where you receive the error message: when you call the stored proc or within the stored proc. Pls also check out the character set and collation of your field and the same for your stored proc.

Comment: Check the collation of the connection.  Check the collation when the Stored Procedure was _created_.

Comment: I think I was mostly tripped up by a bug in MariaDB where it caches the collation for a database and even if you drop and recreate the database, the stored procedures are created with the original collation of the first database created. Now that I have that sorted out the situation is not as bad as my initial experience would suggest.

Comment: There are an awful lot of Q&A on StackOverflow about Maria DB and collation though, so it is clearly an area that creates a lot of difficulty, so a step by step getting started guide would still be helpful.